# Should I use a wrapper or primitive type as field while using Jackson

Tags: java, json, object, jackson, primitive-types

I'm using `Jackson` `JSON` parser. I have simple data transfer object which should be returned via `REST` service.

```
public class PersonDto {

  private String name;
  private Integer age; // int?

  public PersonDto(String name, Integer age) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return this.name;
  }

  public Integer getAge() {
      return this.age;
  }
}
```

Should I favor wrapper classes over primitive types as fields in such case? Which of these approaches has more advantages, except that wrapper is nullable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrapper class: `java.lang.Integer`

Pros:

- Allows `null` value, therefore giving the chance to the user to leave a blank / non-specified field
- Fast when values are between -128 and 127, as it uses its internal cache instead of creating new objects
- `Integer::valueOf` for parsing `String`'s

Cons:

- Immutable: if you have to reset the value (e.g: because it exceeded a certain range), you'll have to re-create a whole new `Integer` instance.
- Slower calculation performance
- `java.lang.Integer` is a reference to an instance. Each calculation will recreate a whole new Object

---

Primitive type: `int`

Pros:

- Mutable (as long as non-`final`, and a `setter` is provided): easily allows: `this.age = age > MAX_AGE ? blabla : age;`
- primitive types calculations are faster
- `Integer::parseInt` for parsing `String`'s

Cons:

- Non-selected values will be automatically set to 0; this may create confusion on whether the user selected 0 as value, or did not select anything

---

It seems the only advantage of `java.lang.Integer` is the `blank` / `null` value.

Also, in cases where a wrapper is needed, e.g:

```
List<Integer> myList;
```

you can directly add an unboxed value `myList.add(2);` which is interpreted by the compiler as `myList.add(Integer.valueOf(2));`

Answer (score 2):

I found using wrapper in DTO's beneficial. With Jackson, for **nullable fields** you can set *@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)* on top of the DTO object and reduce the number of data sent via network (null fields will not be present in resulting JSON), thus resolving ambiguity if value is 0 or not present, telling the front-end that no node is present and hence no processing/displaying data is needed.
For non-nullable numeric data, primitive works well.
Also, for floating-point data that are not supposed to be used in front-end in arithmetic calculations, one can use String with rounding performed on server-side. I saw this technique multiple times in REST API's.

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
    System.out.println(df.format(d));
```